# set of tuples of items in grocery

Tags: set, tuples, c++14, c++17

I was doing a question given vectors of itemName, price, and quantity in which I had to find out how many duplicates are there in them when combined. So I did solve the problem by using the set of tuples but then I thought of unpacking them and print them. **Here's my code:**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<string> name{"ball", "bat", "glove", "glove","glove"};
    vector<int> price{2,3,1,2,1};
    vector<int> w{2,5,1,1,1};
set<tuple<string,int,int>> s;
for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++){
    s.insert({name[i],price[i],w[i]});
}
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
    string st;
    int p; 
    int we;
    tie(st,p,we) = s[i]; **statement**
    cout<<st<<" "<<p<<" "<<we<<'\n';
}
cout<<name.size() - s.size();
return 0;
}
```

But there's an error in the statement line. Can't unpack. Need help. Thanks.

Comment: And the error is...?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant unpack a tuple using tie.
Although, if you are using c++17, you could use structural bindings like this (pardon the indentation):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<string> name{"ball", "bat", "glove", "glove","glove"};
    vector<int> price{2,3,1,2,1};
    vector<int> w{2,5,1,1,1};
     set<tuple<string,int,int>> s;
for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++){
    s.insert({name[i],price[i],w[i]});
}

for(auto tup : s){
    auto [a, b, c] = tup;
    cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<'\n';
}
cout<<name.size() - s.size();
return 0;
}
```

In C++11/14, you might consider printing it directly:

```
cout << get<0>(tup) << " " << get<1>(tup) << " " << get<2>(tup) << endl;
```